# How do you store a googol in the database (and other very large numbers)?

Tags: javascript, database, numbers

How do you efficiently store very large and very small numbers from say `10^-100` to `10^100`, so that you can use them to calculate values in a programming language like JavaScript.

JavaScript stores `10^100` as `1e+101`, is there a way to do that in the database?  The numbers would not often be that large, but I would like to do calculations with data such as `10^-34 * 2^16` or whatever, so the database should (I think) be storing these as numbers...

How does this work?  How do you store numbers of this scale such that you can run computations with them?

By "the database", I'm thinking in general.  I am messing around with MongoDB and Neo4j currently.

Comment: For large numbers, store them as strings. There are javascript libraries for large numbers, such as [bigInt](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html) for integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Databases themselves don't support numbers of arbitrary size in a native numeric format. Your general upper limit on numeric types is usually 8 bytes, which isn't anywhere near a googol.

You'll have to store the number either as a string (least efficient, easiest to work with, can be as precise as needed), as a byte array of arbitrary length (more efficient, harder to work with, still arbitrary precision), or in scientific notation (most efficient, harder to work with, and limited precision).

The first two, unfortunately, do eliminate the possibility of doing any server-side computation, since there wouldn't be a native numeric type that could support the range of valid values. All of the computation would have to be done client-side using a suitable numeric type.

Comment: Why do you say scientific notation has limited precision? One can certainly store 1.2345LotsOfDigits89E1000SomeBigNumber00042.  Not terribly space efficient if you actually need that kind of precision, though generally if you measure something on the order of one googol, you won't care much about the 1's place.

Comment: Because it's true. Scientific notation itself can obviously store numbers to an arbitrary precision, but the point of it is to provide approximations of large numbers using smaller numbers. It's lossy compression. Size, precision, domain; you get to pick two. It may be true that the OP doesn't need that level of precision, in which case scientific notation might certainly be suitable. I don't know, which is why I stated that in the answer.

Comment: Are you talking about some specific machine representation of scientific notation, or the notation in general?  The notation in general allows for a number between 1 and 10 of arbitrary precision, plus an arbitrary exponent.

Comment: @EricJ.: The machine representation, since that's the relevant point. If the database can't store arbitrarily large numbers, then scientific notation is no exception.

Comment: Does MongoDB or Neo4j have a native "scientific notation" format?

Comment: @EricJ.: Double- and single-precision floating-point (i.e. `double` and `single` or `float`) are the standard machine representation formats that store numbers using scientific notation, so I'd be surprised if either of those databases lacked native support for them. They would have a limited range, of course, with the level of precision supported inversely proportional to the size of the number.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd separate the numerical value from the exponent. I personally don't have experience with MongoDB or Neo4j, but in MySQL (I'm sure they have similar terms) I'd create a table with an VARCHAR (text) column with whatever precision you'd like in your program (or how many unique numbers), and another VARCHAR column with length 3 (for max exponent 999). You can tinker with the values as you see fit, but that's all I can think of. If you want more flexible size values, I'd store the numbers on the server's file system using PHP rather than use databases.

Comment: while this seems like a great approach, you will basically need to re-implement the whole floating point standard again. And I would trust that whoever coded the underlying programming language/arithmetic libraries are a lot better than you or me at doing it.

Comment: Yeah... good point. It probably requires a lot more work than I made it sound like, now that I think about it.

Comment: _a lot more work_ is probably the understatement of the year. There is a standard for customizable-precision decimal arithmetics (http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) and it is not simple nor easy

Answer (score 2):

You could use the double type.

[The MySQL  DOUBLE[(M,D)]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

> A normal-size (double-precision) floating-point number. Permissible
>   values are -1.7976931348623157E+308 to -2.2250738585072014E-308, 0,
>   and 2.2250738585072014E-308 to 1.7976931348623157E+308. These are the
>   theoretical limits, based on the IEEE standard. The actual range might
>   be slightly smaller depending on your hardware or operating system.